# Multiple Replace strings in href sharing the same class

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am trying to replace the href of three hyperlinks. Which I can do with the following code:

```js
var url = $('.contact_link').attr('href');
url = url.replace('http://www.contact.nl/', '/');
$('.contact_link').attr('href', url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.contact.nl/Privacypolicy.aspx" class="copyright contact_link">Privacypolicy</a> | <a href="http://www.contact.nl/PrivacyStatement.aspx" class="copyright contact_link">Privacy statement</a> |
<a href="http://www.test.nl" class="copyright">Copyright test</a>| <a href="http://www.contact.nl/Contact.aspx" class="copyright contact_link">Contact</a>
```

Which result in a change of each hyperlink containing the `contact_link` class. But each hyperlink is only updated with the first href. So each hyperlink now contains the URL: "/Privacypolicy.aspx"

How could I achieve that each URL is updated with their corresponding href?

Comment: Why don't you use `replaceAll()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
$('.contact_link').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    url = url.replace('http://www.contact.nl/', '/');
    $(this).attr('href', url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.contact.nl/Privacypolicy.aspx" class="copyright contact_link">Privacypolicy</a> | <a href="http://www.contact.nl/PrivacyStatement.aspx" class="copyright contact_link">Privacy statement</a> |
<a href="http://www.test.nl" class="copyright">Copyright test</a>| <a href="http://www.contact.nl/Contact.aspx" class="copyright contact_link">Contact</a>
```